# Invoking a function twice by two coroutines simultaneously

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines, simultaneous

How to run a function twice by two coroutines simultaneously?
I tried with this code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    launch {
        calculate("first")
    }
    launch {
        calculate("second")
    }
}

fun calculate(name: String) {
    var value = 0
    for (x in 1..1_000){
        value += 1
        if(x % 100 == 0){
            println("calculating $x for $name")
        }
    }
}
```

but second coroutine waits until first coroutine leaves the function, to run it!

How am i gonna to do such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`runBlocking` uses an event loop as a default for the coroutine dispatcher. With an event loop only one coroutine can run on the event thread simultaneously.

You can specify any other dispatcher that uses a thread pool, e.g. `Dispatchers.Default`, to run coroutines simultaneously.

```
fun main() = runBlocking<Unit>(Dispatchers.Default) {
    launch {
        calculate("first")
    }
    launch {
        calculate("second")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Coroutine dispatcher can't jump from one coroutine to another anywhere in your code (like threads do). All non-suspending (blocking) code in coroutine is invoked at once, and only when coroutine is *suspended*, dispatcher can let another coroutine do its work in the same thread.

It means that your function `calculate` must *suspend* your coroutine at some points - for your case, you should call suspending function `yield()`, for example, after each iteration of your loop. This function yields a thread of coroutine dispatcher to other coroutines to run.

```
suspend fun calculate(name: String) {
    var value = 0
    for (x in 1..1_000){
        value += 1
        if(x % 100 == 0){
            println("calculating $x for $name")
        }
        yield()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the code you want to parallelize is not suspendable, you have no good reason to use coroutines. You're basically employing the entire machinery of coroutines just to send a job to a thread pool, and forcing the caller to establish the coroutine scope.

Instead you can just submit tasks to the executor underlying the `IO` dispatcher:

```
fun main() {
    Dispatchers.IO.asExecutor().apply {
        execute { calculate("first") }
        execute { calculate("second") }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this approach takes some more complicated boilerplate to prevent main function or jvm from ending until work is finished Compare to @Rene approach, right?

Comment: Yes, that's true. Still it feels backward to me to engage coroutines for pure executor service work, but it may turn out it's the most convenient way in Kotlin today.